# convert object to array javascript when object has no quotes

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework

I use firebase and I am creating a follow system which pushes in firebase my data like that when I follow:

```
firebase.database().ref('followers/' + followedId).update({ [this.userId]: true });
firebase.database().ref('followings/' + this.userId).update({ [followedId]: true });
```

Then If I would like to display my list of followers / followings, I need an array of object `{followedId: true}`

I need to change the format of the result `[{followedId: true}]` to an array of `followedId`. Hope is more clear.

Comment: Your question is mostly about how you action a follower, but it sounds like you want to change the format of the results. Perhaps update your question to show the results you want to format and the expected structure?

Comment: I copy here some of your comments to my deleted answer, which clarify the things: "I get a list of object object {followedId: true} and the problem is to display this object in html. I need an array of followedId without the ":true"." Therefore, can you share the query you use to get these objects in your html page?

Comment: So the results look something like `[{id1: true}, {id2: true}, {id3: true}]`?

Comment: The best result would be something like     [{"uid":id1,"checked":true}] but if I can have this     [{"uid":id1}] it would be perfect!

Comment: What do the results look like when you pull them from Firebase? Like my above comment?

Comment: When I pull the results from firebase I get an object which look like : {uid1: true,uid2: true,uid3: true,uid4: true}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your results look like `{uid1: true, uid2: true, uid3: true, uid4: true}`

```js
const results = {uid1: true, uid2: true, uid3: true, uid4: true}

const followers = Object.keys(results)

console.log(followers) // ["uid1", "uid2", "uid3", "uid4"]
```

If you need them formatted as per your comment:

```js
const results = {uid1: true, uid2: true, uid3: true, uid4: true}

const followers = Object.keys(results).map(id => ({ uid: id, checked: true }))

console.log(followers)
```

Comment: Fantastic! thank you very much Alex! and sorry for the explanation not super clear...